# How to cout invalid input and then reinput in and if else statement

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and in need of help

```
if(x == "D" || x == "d"){
        cout << "How many 5c coins? ==> ";
        cin >> j;
        five += j;
        cout << "How many 10c coins? ==> ";
        cin >> a;
        ten += a;
        cout << "How many 20c coins? ==> ";
        cin >> q;
        twenty += q;
        cout << "How many 50c coins? ==> ";
        cin >> k;
        fifty += k;
```

I want the user to input an integer so I declared int = j, a, q, k
How to make it that for example so if the user inputted the letter P it will cout an error and the user could reinput

Comment: No, you didn't declare " int = j, a, q, k". Instead of describing what you did, show the code. As little as needed to show the problem, but enough that people reading it can understand what it does.

Comment: I declared it already

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to allow user to re-enter the input in a case when the user enters an invalid input.

You can do:

```
bool validinput = true;

if(x == "D" || x == "d"){
        do{
                validinput = true;
                cout << "How many 5c coins? ==> ";
                cin >> j;
                if (cin.fail()) { 
                        cout << "Please enter a valid value.." << endl;
                        cin.clear(); //reset state bits
                        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //discard all characters from the input buffer, or until a newline is read.
                        validinput = false;
                }
        }while(validinput == false);

//repeat same to validate other numeric inputs
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man! That does it! Thank you thank you youre the best! Oh and now how do I make it so it doesnt accept negative numbers?

Comment: @TengkuFahad: You can add a check for `j < 0` to make the program not to accept the negative number for input `j`. Replace `if (cin.fail())` with `if (cin.fail() || j < 0)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop:

```
do {
  int num;
  if(cin >> num)
  { /* input is good */ 
    ...
    break;
  }
  else
  { /* error */ }
} while(true);
```

Comment: For the error case `std::cin`'s state needs to be cleaned up to be able to receive further input.

Comment: Can you explain more? I'm new to coding and dont really know much sorry.